# Why is this Java code not compiling?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public class MessagePrettier<T> {

    private final T uglyMessage;

    public MessagePrettier(T uglyMessage) {
        this.uglyMessage = uglyMessage;
    }

    public List<String> stringList() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        strings.add("Pretty version of: " + uglyMessage.toString());
        return strings;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessagePrettier<Integer> p = new MessagePrettier<Integer>(new Integer("25"));
        List list = p.stringList();
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

When I compile this code I will get:

```
java: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.String
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

Well stringList() returns a List of Strings, why is the compiler expecting Objects?

Comment: List list = p.stringList(); to List<String> list = p.stringList();

Comment: In the future, when asking about compiler messages, always highlight the line the compiler doesn't like. It makes it much easier to find the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are assigning your `List<String>` to a raw `List` variable :

```
List list = p.stringList();
```

Therefore, iterating over it returns `Object`s.

Change it to :

```
List<String> list = p.stringList();
```